# Cannot submit webform with dalek js

Tags: dalekjs

What is the correct way to click an input element using Dalek JS?

```
<input type="submit" name="submitButton " value="Next Page" id="submitButton" class="btnSubmit">
```

I've tried to submit the form using `.submit('#formName')` or just `.submit()` but this doesn't work (i'm assuming it's because its an asp.net webform)

I've also tried using `.click('.btnSubmit')` which works fine when using PhantomJS, but not when using the using the dalek-browser-chrome.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

interesting issue; first of all, I prefer submitting forms using a click on the submit button because this, in 90%, is the case when a "real" user submits the form.
So, in my humble opinion, this should be the way a Dalek test should handle form submits in most cases.

The interesting part of your question is, that it works in PhantomJS, but not in Chrome. I never seen something like this behaviour before. I encourage you to set up a reduced testcase, may it be a form with just one textinput field & a submit button.
If that works, try to add more elements to the reduced testcase that are also part of your failing testcase. If you hit the point where it stops working, great, we can then start & debug from that point on.

Additionally, if you start DalekJS with the additional `-l 5` parameter like so `dalek myTest.js -b chrome -l 5` that will make Dalek extremely chatty & output all the communication between Dalek & the Browser. Please check if any security or privacy relevant data is in there & mask it. Please then go ahead & post this here or send it to me via mail (dalekjs@asciidisco.com).